# How to rank based on exponential decay using a database

Tags: postgresql, django-orm, ranking

I'm trying to rank based on hotness following Evan Miller's advice here - http://www.evanmiller.org/rank-hotness-with-newtons-law-of-cooling.html

My model has two fields for this: temperature and time since last reading.
Updating the hotness is easy.  My problem is that the temperature stored in the database is not the up-to-date temperature, it is the calculated temperature at the time of last reading.

So when I do `Link.objects.all().order_by('-temperature')` a link that has had no votes will always have a high temperature.

What I would like to do is something along the lines of

```
Link.objects.all().order_by('temperature' * e^(-cooling_param*hours_since_last_reading))
```

But I can't find any similar examples.

I'm using the Django ORM and Postgres

Thanks!